# function-like macro versus macros

Tags: c, macros

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

I have been looking at a test suite and I noticed this function-like macro declared like this:

```
#define MU_SUITE_START() char *msg = NULL
```

However, is there any real difference to doing just this instead:

```
#define MU_SUITE_START char *msg = NULL
```

Macros just do text replacement so I don't think there is going to be any performance issues.

Using cpp I get the following results so nothing special here.

function-like macro

```
char *msg = __null;
```

marco

```
char *msg = __null;
```

Just a side note: Is it worth declaring a function-like marco that doesn't provide in input parameters?
Here I am not passing any parameters
i.e.

```
#define PRINT_MSG() printf("This is the message\n")
```

Why bother with the function-like macro if there are no input parameters, isn't this better?

```
#define PRINT_MSG printf("This is the message\n")
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Part of it is readability. If it's gonna behave like a function, why not make it look like one as well?

Comment: If you're going to have a function-like macro then *please* wrap it in a `do-while(false)` so I can't do this: `unsigned MU_SUITE_START() + 10000;` Actually wait, that wouldn't work here. Better advice: don't use macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's one difference between the object-like and function-like macros:

```
#define OBJECT     char *msg1 = NULL
#define FUNCTION() char *msg2 = NULL

void somefunc(void)
{
    int OBJECT = 5;
    int FUNCTION = 10;
    ...
}
```

The declaration for `OBJECT` is replaced by the macro (so the code won't compile), but the reference to FUNCTION is not a macro invocation because it is not followed by an open parenthesis.

This is seldom important.  However, when it is, it really matters.

A more typical case might be a function that can be implemented as a macro.  For sake of discussion (because it is easily understood rather than because it is a good example):

```
extern int isdigit(int c);
#define isdigit(c) ((c) >= '0' && (c) <= '9')
```

and in an implementation file:

```
int (isdigit)(int c)
{
    assert((c >= 0 && c <= UCHAR_MAX) || c == EOF);
    return isdigit(c);
}
```

Ignoring little details like that isn't how `isdigit()` is likely to be implemented, and a macro implementation of `isdigit()` is not allowed to evaluate its argument more than once, and you aren't supposed to redefine things that are in the standard C library, the function definition is not macro expanded because the name `isdigit` is not followed by `(`, but the macro inside the function is expanded.  At least the function is implemented in terms of the macro, which pretty much guarantees the same behaviour.

Comment: Did I overlook something, or are your definitions for `OBJECT` and `FUNCTION` exactly the same?